# posgresql9.4 remote connection fail

Tags: postgresql

We have issues connecting to our PostgreSQL server. Sometimes nobody can connect, sometimes some can and some can't. We have no idea why.

The PostgreSQL server is on a virtual machine with 4GB of memory. We have 3 poeple who want to connect to that server. Could it be possible that number of connections are over the default *max_connection*?

Error message:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "192.x.x.x" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Network problems, by the sounds. Show the **exact text** of the error message(s) you get please.

Comment: Network, firewall, ...  Can you ping the DB host when the connection is unsuccessful (and can you when it succeeds)?

Comment: This error is not due to too many connections, it's network problems like others have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you all.Today the db is normal.I think it's really network problem as you said

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a network problem, restart the virtual machine and try again. The whole vm might be needing just a restart.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have network issues, although withojt further details specifying the "sometimes" when your connection *does* work, it's hard to tell. It could be something like your server is not configured to listen on that specific network interface (check `pg_hba.conf` and make sure, like [the manual entry in this link explains](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)) or you might have some other piece of software interfering, such as a firewall. Maybe the times when the connection does work somehow trigger a different rule, which allows them to connect.

As other answers state, a reboot might be a good  starting point, but if you haven't done anything weird regarding network config I doubt that will fix it.